# How to format a decimal and string as part of a hybrid expression?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

### Question

I created a hybrid property which is composed of a string and a decimal formatted as percentage but I am getting a TypeError when using the hybrid expression. I've tried several variations on the f-string including converting it to float first but I still get the error on the same line. What is the best way to do this string formatting and concatenation on the hybrid property expression?

I want to know why 'result_1' is producing an error, and 'result_2' works correctly

### Model

```py
from decimal import Decimal as D
class SupplierDiscount(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tblSupplierDiscount"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    discount = Column(DECIMAL(5, 4), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
    
    
    @hybrid_property
    def disc_desc(self):
        return f'{self.description}: {self.discount * 100:.4f}%'


    @disc_desc.expression
    def disc_desc(cls):
        return f'{cls.description}: {cls.discount * 100:.4f}%' # Error generated here
```

### result_1 - Preferred method - but results in error

```py
result_1 = session.query(SupplierDiscount.id.label("SDId"),
                         SupplierDiscount.disc_desc.label("SDDDesc")
                         ).all()
print('Below is from result_1')
print(result_1)
for i in result_1:
    print(i.id, i.disc_desc)
```

### Error produced in result_1

```py
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to BinaryExpression.__format__
```

### result_2 - This works but this is not the preferred method

```py
result_2 = session.query(SupplierDiscount).all()
print('Below is from result_2')
print(result_2)
for i in result_2:
    print(i.id, i.disc_desc)
```

### Environment

```py
SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
PostgreSQL 13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a distinction between class-level and instance-level access. The hybrid property is used on instance-level and uses python string formatting to get the desired result. As the expression is used for class-level access this needs to be defined as an SQL expression to return the desired result. See the [`docs`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior) for reference.

Knowing this we can rewrite the code to the following to achieve the same result on class-level and instance-level:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine, DECIMAL, String, func
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

Base = declarative_base()

class Discount(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Discount'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String)
    discount = Column(DECIMAL(5,4))

    @hybrid_property
    def disc_desc(self):
        return f'{self.description}: {self.discount * 100:.4f}%'

    @disc_desc.expression
    def disc_desc(cls):
        return cls.description + ' ' + func.cast(cls.discount * 100, String) + '%'


engine = create_engine(dburl)

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    discount = Discount(description='test', discount=5.4)

    session.add(discount)
    session.commit()

    disc = session.query(Discount).first()
    print('Instance-level access')
    print(disc.disc_desc)
    print('')

    disc = session.query(Discount.disc_desc).first()
    print('Class-level access')
    print(disc.disc_desc)
```

This results in:

```sh
Instance-level access
test: 540.0000%

Class-level access
test: 540.0000%
```